# Pie chart amchart4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am using the amchart4 pie charts in my web application. I want the labels to be visible only for large screens like desktops, tablets and laptops.

When it comes to mobile view the labels should be hidden. How do I achieve that?

```
pieSeries.labels.template.disabled = true;
```

Helps hiding the labels , but I want labels visbile in large screens only. Please assist me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the tooltips with

```
@media all (max-width: 400px)
{
  #chart_id g[role="tooltip"]
  {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have just copy/pasted it instead of replacing `chart_id` with the ID of your chart ?